# Is there any way to Load Spark SQL resultset (data frames ) back to cassandra?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I have queried Cassandra using spark in Scala. Below is the result:

[image]

Is there any way to write this result back to Cassandra tables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map( "table" -> "t_payu_df", "keyspace" -> "ks_payu"))
  .save()
```

This will work.

You can also specify SaveMode (overwrite,append,ErrorIfExists).

Example with SaveMode:

```
df.write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .options(Map( "table" -> "t_payu_df", "keyspace" -> "ks_payu"))
  .save()
```

For more details visit [Dataframe](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md)

Comment: Thanks @undefined_variable, is there any chance of creating cassandra table on the go ? , based on the dataframe. here above we are creating the table first and then moving data from data frame to cassandra table.

Comment: @Goutham in the link there are steps for creating table on the go as well

Comment: Yes @undefined_variable, in method createCassandraTable there we have to give the partitionKeyColumns and clusteringKeyColumns. ok now I got it , it is mandatory to define these as cassandra work that way.. thank you ..