# Is there any way to insert pandas dataframe to cassandra db?

Tags: python, pandas, cassandra, pyspark

I've a Panda's data Frame and I need to load it to cassandra database. 
It is also okay if the dataframe is pyspark dataframe.
I followed this link but that is for scala. Is there any way simillar to the below link?

[Is there any way to Load Spark SQL resultset (data frames ) back to cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994053/is-there-any-way-to-load-spark-sql-resultset-data-frames-back-to-cassandra)

Comment: For the most part, that DataFrame API is the exact same...

Comment: I tried it but got syntax error

Comment: Can you please show what you tried?

Comment: Please, *do not post code in the comments section!* Edit your post instead!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
asset_details.write\
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")‌​\
.mode('Overw‌​rite')\
.options(table="asset_data", keyspace="recommendation")\
.save()
```

[Saving Dataframe to cassandra using python](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md#saving-a-dataframe-in-python-to-cassandra)

Comment: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o76.save.

Comment: try using escape... edited answer